# Файл exe сделанный в launch4j не работает на другом компьютере

Tags: java, jar, exe

После упаковки проекта из jar в exe, на этом компьютере все работает, но на другом выдает ошибку

> a JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.

Насколько мне понятно из того, что удалось погуглить, ему не хватает jdk  и я не могу понять, как его приложить к exe, и почему launch4j этого не делает.

Тут был похожий вопрос, где на другом компьютере вылетала ошибка, что нет установленной java, и на него был дан следующий ответ, который я не понимаю:

> Вам надо использовать следующую конфигурацию для упаковки JRE в выполняемый файл

```
<jre>
     <path>путь/jre</path> 
</jre>
```

Уже несколько часов не могу с этим разобраться

Comment: Оказывается, можно привязать JRE к exe при помощи Inno Setup. Но я снова не понимаю, как.

Comment: И почему приложение не видит JNI если java на другом компе установлена?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net

> The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one.

### docs

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

#### Configuration file

```
<path>bundled JRE path (%VAR%)</path>
<jdkPreference>jreOnly|preferJre|preferJdk|jdkOnly</jdkPreference>
```

#### `<path>`

> The `<path>` property is used to specify the absolute or relative path (to the executable) of a bundled JRE, ...

используется для указания пути к "bundled JRE"

#### `<jdkPreference>`

> Optional, defaults to preferJre; Allows you to specify a preference for a public JRE or a private JDK runtime. Valid values are:

Опцианальная, по умолчанию `preferJre`; позволяет выбрать между "public JRE" и "private JDK" окружением. Валидные ключи:

- `jreOnly` - Always use a public JRE (equivalent to the old option dontUsePrivateJres=true)
- `preferJre` - Prefer a public JRE, but use a JDK private runtime if it is newer than the public JRE (equivalent to the old option dontUsePrivateJres=false)
- `preferJdk` - Prefer a JDK private runtime, but use a public JRE if it is newer than the JDK
- `jdkOnly` - Always use a private JDK runtime (fails if there is no JDK installed)